# Convert key=value pair from jq output to comma seperated string

Tags: json, jq

I have this json stored in a variable `foo`

```
{
"app":   "myApp",
"env":   "test",
"tier":  "frontend"
}
```

I have converted it into key=value pair using the following jq command:

```
jq -r 'to_entries[] | (.key) + "=" + .value' <(echo "$foo")
```

Output:

```
app =  myApp
env =  test
tier= frontend
```

I need to transform this to a comma seperated string of following string format and store in a variable:

Expected Output:

```
app=myApp,env=test,tier=frontend
```

What I tried:

```
jq -r 'to_entries[] | (.key) + "=" + .value| join(",")' <(echo "$foo")
```

But got error  `jq: error (at <stdin>:4): Cannot iterate over string ("app=myApp")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`join()` works on an array, but you're returning single items.

Replace `[]` with `map()` so we keep the array, then `join` will work just fine:

```
to_entries | map(.key + "=" + .value) | join(",")
```

---

###### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/qET5nEYatIR)